# Argh, makefile won't pick up dependencies correctly

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

My simple little makefile is exhibiting behavior which I'm not able to understand. If I touch any source file except Dictionary.cpp then no targets are built, and if I touch Dictionary.cpp then it compiles but doesn't link. Source files are in src/ object (.o) and dependencies (.d) are in obj/ and binary goes into bin/

If I rm obj/* then everything builds OK but the timestamps don't seem to be being picked up. Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

The .d files seem to be being created correctly, here's Dictionary.d:

```
obj/Dictionary.o: src/Dictionary.cpp src/pch.h src/Types.h src/Util.h \
 src/Refcount.h src/Dictionary.h
src/Dictionary.cpp:
src/pch.h:
src/Types.h:
src/Util.h:
src/Refcount.h:
src/Dictionary.h:
```

Which looks correct to me. Here's the makefile:

```
sources =   Dictionary.cpp  \
            Util.cpp        \
            Tile.cpp        \
            Board.cpp       \
            Vec2.cpp        \
            Letter.cpp      \
            Random.cpp      \
            Server.cpp      \
            main.cpp

objects = $(patsubst %.cpp,obj/%.o,$(sources))
depends = $(patsubst %.cpp,obj/%.d,$(sources))

CXX = g++
CPPFLAGS = -Isrc -std=c++0x
CXXFLAGS = -c

-include $(depends)

bin/dictionary: $(objects)
    @echo Link...
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(objects) -o bin/dictionary -lrt

obj/%.o: src/%.cpp
    @echo [$*]
    @$(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) src/$*.cpp -o obj/$*.o
    @$(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) -MM src/$*.cpp -MF obj/$*.d
    @mv -f obj/$*.d obj/$*.d.tmp
    @sed -e 's|.*:|obj/$*.o:|' < obj/$*.d.tmp > obj/$*.d
    @sed -e 's/.*://' -e 's/\\$$//' < obj/$*.d.tmp | fmt -1 | sed -e 's/^ *//' -e '    s/$$/:/' >> obj/$*.d
    @rm -f obj/$*.d.tmp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to move the `include` to the end, or put the `bin/dictionary` rule before it, or add an `all: bin/dictionary` rule before the include, or something.

Or, resign yourself to always running `make bin/dictionary`, which will work as well.

Remember make, by default, tries to build the first target in the makefile.  Because you have the `include` line before any other target, the first target defined by an `include`d file will be considered the default goal, and that happens to be `obj/Dictionary.o`.